# Can multiple yarn applications get created for one HIVE query?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn

I have noticed whenever I am adding self join in my HIVE query multiple yarn application gets started.
My HIVE query is running on Spark

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the design documents for [Spark on Yarn](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark#HiveonSpark-3.Hive-LevelDesign).  And [Joins](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Join+Design+Master#HiveonSpark:JoinDesignMaster-Figure2:JoinProcessorsforHiveonSpark) on (spark on yarn).  They aren't as clear as they used to be (some images are missing) but it might help give you a good understanding of what happens and why.

Comment: If you feel this answer was helpful and you are comfortable could you mark it as correct?